# Can I save data in guard before loading page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-router

Current routing configuration:

```
  //...
  {
    path: 'foo/:id',
    component: SomeComponent,
    canActivate: [SomeGuard]
  },
  //...
```

Then in guard I call permission service to get access for component:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private service: Service) {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const id = parseInt(next.params['id']);

    return this.service.getPermissions(id).then(permissions => {
      if (permissions.canView) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

But in the component I utilize the same permissions endpoint, which means I call it twice in a row to get to one page:

```
 //...
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private service: Service) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);

    this.service.getPermissions(this.id).then(permissions => {
        // ...
    });
  }
  //...
```

So it would be great to just save the permissions data in the route and utilize it by both guard and the component. I tried using `resolve`, but it turns out `resolve` only activates after the guards, which is no good. So how can i save permissions data?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the kind of task for a caching service. Permissions do not change often so they are the perfect candidate for caching. That way even multiple visits to the same resource would not trigger multiple HTTP requests for permission checks.

**Edit:** Since you need permissions to be loaded each time, you could listen for `RouteNavigationStart` and clear the cache. If this becomes too cumbersome to maintain in the `PermissionsService` you could extract the logic into a separate service.

You could something like this in the service you use to get your permissions:

```
// Permissions service
private permissionCache;

constructor(
    router: Router,
) {
    // clear cache when a route navigation starts
    router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
        .subscribe(event => this.permissionCache = {})
}

getPermissions(id) {
    if (permissionCache[id]) {
        return Observable.of(permissionCache[id]);
    } else {
        // get the permissions
        permissionCache[id] = response;
        return Observable.of(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, caching does not cut it here, permissions have to be reloaded each time.

Comment: You could listen for route changes and clear the cache. That way you would call the server on every route change. Edited the answer appropriately. Would match your use-case?